# Call method repeatedly even after app removed using RxJava2

Tags: android, rx-java2

My aim is to call a REST API and get its result repeatedly even when app is removed from minimised state. For the time being, since I'm new in RxJava, I'm just trying to print the result of a boolean being fetched from a method. I searched a lot and found this tutorial [link](https://blog.aritraroy.in/the-missing-rxjava-2-guide-to-supercharge-your-android-development-part-1-624ef326bff4). But prob is my code is not fetching the result in .subscribe() part. Also once I remove the app from minimised state, the .subscribe stops.

```js
public class Movie {

    private boolean state;

    public boolean isState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(boolean state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
}
```

```css
private Movie getMovies(){
        Movie movie = new Movie();
        movie.setState(true);
        return movie;
    }
```

```html
Observable<Movie> movieObservable = Observable.create(emitter -> {
                    try {
                        // Fetches Movie objects from the network, database, etc.
                        Movie movie = getMovies();
                        emitter.onNext(movie);
                        emitter.onComplete();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        emitter.onError(e);
                    }
                });

                movieObservable.interval(1000, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(movie -> {
                            // Use your movie item here
                            System.out.println("SAM: movie: "+movie);
                        }, throwable -> {
                            // Handle the error here
                            System.out.println("SAM: error");
                        });
```

Comment: "even when app is removed from minimised state" --> I think you need to have a look at https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

Comment: @ExpensiveBelly I checked it. It cannot be used when you need to do something immediately. My API call will give some value which needs to be put into push notification. And this process should be called every hour even if the app is killed. So don't think WorkManager should be used

Comment: Then you need to schedule alarms but Google discourages that approach because it drains battery: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms

Answer (score 0):

I thinks you have just to inverse your operators, start with the interval and then launch the request to get the movie.

```java
...
Observable.interval(1, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
   .concatMap(l -> movieObservable)
...
```

Another thing, You must change the initialDelay of the `interval` operator from `1000`, to `1` as you using `TimeUnit.SECONDS`